# millisecond timing in java

Tags: java, events, calendar, timing

I time various transactions in my Java application.   At the start of the transaction, I get a start time by instantiating a Calendar and then getting the hour, minute, second, and millisecond.    I complete the transaction, instantiate a new Calendar and get a new hour, minute, second, and millisecond.    My reasoning is that the difference between the start time and the end time is the time of the transaction.   This seems to work most of the time, but a tiny fraction of the time, the end time is earlier than the start time.    Why would this occur and how can I prevent it?

Comment: What does the code look like, where you create the dates, and call your transaction method?

Comment: If you also show some code which you written to do this then that will be easy to say something....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for one thing a simpler way of computing the difference would be to use something like `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()` - that way you don't need to do anything other than just a simple subtraction to get the number of milliseconds or the number of nanoseconds between the start and the end.

However, if your system clock is being updated by NTP or something similar, then time may effectively go backwards occasionally - depending on how clock skew is handled. (Some systems just slow down the system clock for a while to skew it back to reality; others may have discontinuities.)

I'm not sure of the best way of avoiding this - I don't *believe* the JRE currently has anything equivalent to `Stopwatch` in .NET, which is purely for measuring intervals and doesn't (I believe) get messed up by the system clock changing.

(I go along with Erick's recommendation of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), btw - although I don't think you need it for this particular problem.)

Comment: From my experience, timing is much more precise on linux than windows. System.currentTimeInMilis tends to skip forward in bigger chunks on windows...  Not sure if that will matter, but it could

Comment: IIUC, System.nanoTime is not affected by wall-time changes (such as NTP, etc.). nanoTime is meant for the sole purpose of measuring elapsed time.